# BarChart labels at the same height

Tags: plotting

In this BarChart:

```
BarChart[{573, 604, 519},
 FrameLabel -> {"", ""},
 ChartLabels -> Placed[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ {"a", "b", "c"}, Top],
 PlotRange -> {All, {400, 600}},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic},
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Arial", Black},
 BarSpacing -> {0.1, 0.5},
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3]],
 PlotRangeClipping -> True]
```

I would like to see the labels positioned at the same height, let us say 500.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1. Post-process to modify label positions

A quick hack: With `bc =  BarChart[...]` from your post:

```
ReplaceAll[Text[t_, Offset[o_, {x_, y_}], b___] :> 
   Text[t, Offset[o, {x, 500}], b]] @ bc
```

[image]

#### 2. Use the option [`LabelingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LabelingFunction.html):

This, hopefully, is more flexible and robust:

```
labelingFunction[pos_ : 500] := Placed[#3[[2, 1]], 
   {.5, pos / #}, Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &] &;
```

Add the option `LabelingFunction -> labelingFunction[]` to `BarChart[...]` to get

[image]

Use `LabelingFunction -> labelingFunction[550]`

[image]

#### 3. Use `Labeled` to wrap input data:

```
labeleddata = MapThread[
   Labeled[#, Rotate[#2, 90 Degree], {.5, 500/#}] &]@
 {{573, 604, 519}, {"a", "b", "c"}};
```

Use `labeleddata` as input data and remove the option `ChartLabels -> ...` from `BarChart[...]` to get

[image]